# ReflectionMethod Invoke on doctrine entity returns proxies

Tags: php, symfony, reflection, doctrine-orm

i'm trying to invoke an entity getter with reflection but it returns some strange objects:

> Proxies__CG__\Foo\InvoiceBundle\Entity\Invoice

instead of

> Foo\InvoiceBundle\Entity\Invoice

Here is my code:

```
class ProperProperty extends \ReflectionProperty{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    private function getGetterName($propertyName){
        $ret = "get" . ucfirst($propertyName);
        return $ret;
    }

    public function getDoctrineValue($class, $object){
        $propertyName = $this->getName();
        $getterName = $this->getGetterName($propertyName);
        $reflectionMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($class, $getterName);
        $ret = $reflectionMethod->invoke($object);
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

I saw that proxy classes where kinda lazy-loaded object, is there anyway to force this load ?
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested of how to fill your empty proxy:

```
protected function loadProxy($object){
        $class = get_class($object);
        if (strpos($class, "Proxies") === false)
            return;

        $methodName = "__load";
        $reflectionMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($class, $methodName);
        $ret = $reflectionMethod->invoke($object);
    }
```